# How to save pyprover object with pickle

Tags: python, attributes, pickle, dill

I want to save logical expressions of pyprover with pickle.
The following is the code I wrote in google corabolatory.

```py
!pip install pyprover
import pickle
from pyprover import *

logic = ~A & B

print(1,logic)
print(2,type(logic))
print(3,type(A))

with open("test.pickle","wb") as f:
  pickle.dump(logic,f)

with open("test.pickle","rb") as f:
  logic2 = pickle.load(f) # error

print(logic2)
```

The output is below

```
1 ~A & B
2 <class 'pyprover.logic.And'>
3 <class 'pyprover.logic.Prop'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-4cd4fe38fcb4> in <module>
     12 
     13 with open("test.pickle","rb") as f:
---> 14   logic2 = pickle.load(f) # error
     15 
     16 print(logic2)

AttributeError: 'Top' object has no attribute 'elems'
```

How can I save the logical expression with pickle?
[pyprover github](https://github.com/evhub/pyprover)

If you know how to save the object, I do not care about whether or not it uses pickle. I tried dill,only to get the same result as pickle.

I wrote an [dill issue here](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/549)

I tried to import modules like this but it didn't solve the problem.

```py
import dill 
import pyprover
from pyprover import *
from pyprover.logic import *
from pyprover.parser import *
from pyprover.constants import *
from pyprover.atoms import *
from pyprover.util import *
from pyprover.tools import *
from pyprover.__coconut__ import *
from pyprover.__init__ import *
```

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  Can you (a) try again, but with `dill.detect.trace(True)` and print out the traceback? (b) also try changing `dill.settings['recurse'] = True` to use a serialization variant?  It's an unusual error (especially that it fails on `load`), so it would be good to see a traceback of the `dump`.  Feel free to fill out an issue on the `dill` GitHub.  It would also be good to know which versions of `Python`, `pyprover`, and `dill` you are using.

Comment: I wrote an [issue](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/549).